# Restrain stat_summary errorbars within specified y-axis range in violin plot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation, errorbar, violin-plot

I'm creating a violin plot and am wanting to add a

```
stat_summary
```

argument to show the mean and standard deviation/errorbars for each group. However, when I do this, the y-axis is reorientated so that the origin is no longer at 0, as the errorbars go below 0.

A value below 0 doesn't make sense for the data, so I'm wondering if there is a way I can force the axis to start at 0, and crop/restrain the error bars so they remain inside the plot?

The code for my plot:

```
  ggplot(data=scatrichnessordered, aes(x=ReleaseTime, y=ASVCount, fill=ReleaseTime)) +
    geom_violin(scale="count") +
    theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, linewidth =.5),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+ ylab("Observed Richness (ASV)") + labs(fill="Release Time")+
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
     stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="pointrange", color="black", show.legend = "FALSE")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#fde725","#7ad151", "#31688e"))
```

Which produces the following, which is what I want apart from the issue with the axis:
[Violin-Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk2WB.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `limits = c(0, NA)` to your `scale_y_continuous()`? I.e. replace `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+` with `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))+`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the idea - this does restrict the axis, but also removes the error bars for the two categories with bars going below 0

Comment: Oh, sorry - does adding `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA)) +` to your code give you your desired outcome?

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @Charlotte :)